# Are dominance hierarchies always maintained through violence?

Tags: sociality

Is there a species in which a dominance contest cannot escalate to a fight? I don't know of any but I'm not a biologist.

Comment: I too cannot think of any such species. I think dominance is simply based on "if you are a better alpha male, then defeat me" rather than "if you are a better alpha male, then be more patient than me" ;)